# Alternative for "to recap" to end a presentation

Tags: synonyms

I need a find alternative to "to recap" so as to conclude a presentation in a decent way. Can you please provide your alternatives?

Comment: _Summarize_ -- for instance, you can say (and many do) "Finally, to summarize: ....." or "In summary, .....".

Comment: [recap synonym](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/recap%5Bnoun%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **summarize** or **sum up**. Sum up sounds a bit more informal though IMO but not very much so.

Perhaps you could also say "**In review**..."?